# ? in my file name

Tags: c#, windows, file

is there any way to write ? mark in a file name

Comment: I am talking about saving this file on my windows server and actually the one who write the file name are my site visitors ,so I can’t control there entries ,but upon your answers here I understand that there is limitations for file names such as “< > : " / \ | ? *” so I guess what I am going to do,
Is to let them write whatever they want to write then I will cut these invalid characters and save it in hidden control, and save the file upon their entries but without these characters.
Thank you all

Comment: Having users decide about file names on your server is not a good idea. It is far better to generate unique names yourself. Problems are e.g. conflicts with existing files, and even worse you will have to filter *all* variations for '..\' yourself to make sure no bad stuff happens.

Comment: An alternative is to encode those invalid characters into something that doesn't use invalid characters (something like URL encoding the invalid chars).  That way you won't have to save 'the real, user visible filename' off somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since it is a wildcard such as * is.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx):

Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:

```
* The following reserved characters:

  < > : " / \ | ? *
* Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
* Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31,except for streams. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
```

Comment: Somehow, I managed to copy a file from an ext3 filesystem on linux to an ntfs partition called "file:", with a colon (using ntfs-3g). I have never been able to change or delete it, it has just remained at the root of my drive for more than a year now.

Answer (score 11):

On a windows platform?  No this is an invalid character for names in the windows file system.

The Wikipedia entry on file names has a pretty extensive breakdown on what characters are reserved for various operating systems and file system combos.  Here is the link

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Comment: and even if you managed to do so somehow, no standard API would be able to read the file

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember that you could do something like this way back when with MS-DOS if you used one of the v1.x functions (using an FCB instead of a file handle).  I wonder if any even remotely recent versions of Windows would successfully run such a beast (assuming that I'm event right about DOS letting you do it)?

Drop a note if you decide to give it a try (if you can even dig up the tools).

Comment: +1 for remembering such a dated bit of information.  Basically, it would work for any version of DOS through at least 5, but you had to use the older functions. Even then it was strongly recommended that you NOT do this.

Comment: As soon as they come out with a Software Development version of Trivial Pursuit I'm golden.  Hmm, now that I think about it, "Trival Pursuit" is pretty much the answer to a trivia question nowadays.  I guess I better get back to organizing my floppy disks and arguing about whether the 'Designated Hitter Rule' will ruin baseball.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NTFS article in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), it is possible to use other characters:

> In Posix namespace, any UTF-16 code unit (case sensitive) except U+0000 (NUL) and / (slash)

I don't know if you must have a separated partition for that, or a different API calls into the POSIX system would allow you to use special characters.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the Linux and OSX file systems, although I am pretty sure that Windows does not permit this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write ? in a file name just like you can have a file without a name and only an extension.

This would require an FTP upload or opening the media in ASCII format.

Comment: So how could I?!!!
considering that I am asking in winows Operating system

Thak you,